# listView and ScrollView

Tags: android

I have a linearlayout with 3 imageView and a listview in vertical orientation.i want to scroll the full screen including the images when the user scrolls the list.is that possible?thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#222222"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ph2" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ph1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ph2" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ll4_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you put your layout xml file snippet? All of them that are involved

Comment: Yes... it should be possible. Why don't you just try it? There will probably be issues though, since the `ListView` already has a scroll built in

Comment: i have tried to use scrollview with listview but i only see the first item of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to put the ListView inside of the ScrollView, but it's certainly possible to include the images. I would recommend considering putting the layout with the images in a header to the ListView. See [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29). This [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101739/android-listview-with-complex-header) may also be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

You should search api , the scrollView can not be inner more than one child , must has one direct child