# Remove the header's background in listview

Tags: java, android

I have a listview that i added an header, but i don't want the listview background to come around the header. Like they are two different views (I don't want to put the listview inside the scrollview)

The listview :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.example.tuto.customs.CustomHoverView
    android:id="@+id/chv_activity_list_with_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_activity_list_with_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/carreblanc"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
         >
    </ListView>
</com.example.tuto.customs.CustomHoverView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The header :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

BaseAdapter class:-

```
  private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> strings;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> strings) {
        inflater =  (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.strings = strings;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return strings.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return strings.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder h;
        if(v == null){
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_strings, null);
            h = new ViewHolder();
            h.tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_adapter_strings);
            v.setTag(h);
        }else{
            h = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        if(position == 0){
                    // here it changes the first item, but not the header
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        h.tv.setText(""+getItem(position));
        return v;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView tv;
    }
}
```

The adapter :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_adapter_strings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: handle that on your adapter,

Comment: Can you explain further ?

Comment: change background of your view on getView method when position is equal 0 and set another background for when position not equal 0

Comment: Nothing, actually header is not a part of the adapter, so i can't remove the header's background

Comment: Did you take another layout for header????

Comment: Yes i did, i've just updated the code

Comment: see my updated answer , hope it will help your

Comment: i don't get your mean, if your header is out of listView so what is the problem, just change background of that, and if header is first row of your list so why position not working?

Comment: I want to remove it completely, not change it (that was one of the answer i tried, just in case)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101739/android-listview-with-complex-header

Comment: Did you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can create header.xml with separate background and then add it to the listview

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, myListView, false);
myListView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812191/android-listview-with-fixed-header-and-footer)

Comment: that's what i did, but it still takes the background of my listview

Comment: did you set header background to some other color?

Comment: No i didn't, there is just the listview background

Comment: so add the background in header xml file and check once

Comment: There is a background alright, but there is still the listview'background behind.

Answer (score 0):

header.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Write this in your Activity:-

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            ViewGroup mTop = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header,listView,false);
            listView.addHeaderView(mTop, null, false);
```

Comment: It changed the header background, but what i want is to remove it. Even if i use another background, i can see the listview's background behind

Comment: What you actually want??

Comment: Like the title says : i want to remove the header's background, because it's seems it's embedded in the listview